# How to remove periods with no data from a datetime axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

So I have a dataframe with a datetime index. I removed rows for certain periods, but when I plot the data, matplotlib still shows the removed periods (example: 2021-03-21 to 2021-03-24).
[image]

Here is a call to those periods:

```
df['2021-03-21':'2021-03-23]
```

[image]

This is the code for the plot:

```
dfStd = df.resample('d').std()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,3))
bp = sns.barplot(x = dfStd.index.strftime('%d-%b'), y='Feed_tph', data=dfStd , color='darkorange', ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Dry Feed [tph]')
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
```

How can I remove those periods from the plot?

Comment: Can you edit the question and some code that reproduces the problem? Makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

remove the unwanted bars from the dataframe

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "time": pd.concat([pd.Series(pd.date_range(d, freq="D", periods=6))
                           for d in pd.date_range("1-jun-2021", freq="10D", periods=4)]),
        "Feed_tph": np.random.uniform(1,10, 6*4)}).set_index("time")

# insert some NaNs..
df2 = pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()), dtype="float64", name="filler")
df = df.join(df2, how="right").drop(columns=["filler"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(16,3))
bp = sns.barplot(x = df.index.strftime('%d-%b'), y='Feed_tph', data=df , color='darkorange', ax=ax[0])
df = df.dropna()

bp = sns.barplot(x = df.index.strftime('%d-%b'), y='Feed_tph', data=df , color='darkorange', ax=ax[1])

for i in range(len(ax)):
    ax[i].set_ylabel('Dry Feed [tph]')
    ax[i].set_xlabel('')
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(ax[i].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Actually I had already tried converting the datetime index to strings, and it worked, but, doing that is very inneficient as it takes very long to show the plots, and in my analysis I have to create +20 plots. Is there a way in which you keep the datetime index?